# Что значит "привести разговор"

Tags: значения, словоупотребление, узус

In the following passage:

“Разговор, который я только что привел, – невозмутимо продолжал я, не обращая внимания на его насмешку, – происходил на борту космического корабля.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"привести"** is used here in the same meaning as in "приводить пример", "приводить доказательства" (to give an example, to produce a proof), i.e. to cite, to show something. In general this meaning can be summarized as "to tell, to use some information to support your point of view and opinion".

Answer (score 1):

The conversation I quoted (put here).